# changing body.style.overflowY or X programmatically

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the body `overflowY` to `"hidden"` through a JavaScript function. I've tried both of the following:

```
document.body.style['overflow-y'] = 'hidden';
document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
```

In both cases it didn't work. However in both cases using just `overflow` without X or Y works fine!

Is there a way to change only the `overflowY` or `overflowX` properties?

Comment: The second method is correct. However test with multiple browsers, and document.body.style might not be compatible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both cases should work in all the current browsers.  I've just tested Firefox 4, Chrome 11 and IE 9 and they all work fine.  Either the browser you're testing with has a bug or your problem lies elsewhere in your code; for instance, a conflicting style declaration or erroneous code in the same block.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
}
```

```css
body { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean cursus quam eget odio lacinia varius. Proin non mauris lacus, non dapibus diam. Sed et metus eros. Suspendisse nec leo ut lorem dictum pulvinar eget in lorem. In sem ligula, consectetur nec auctor ut, porttitor eget ante. Cras eu mollis velit. Sed massa ligula, sollicitudin vitae dapibus vel, blandit a massa. Morbi id massa ullamcorper felis posuere vestibulum. Aenean eu risus id orci condimentum bibendum eu eu odio. Vivamus consectetur neque ut arcu condimentum sed sollicitudin turpis convallis. Donec felis leo, posuere non pretium a, laoreet ut massa. Nullam at nunc nulla. Maecenas et orci vel diam malesuada lacinia. Praesent eu accumsan massa.

Cras metus tellus, consequat sit amet bibendum sit amet, pretium ut elit. Vivamus pharetra suscipit est quis posuere. Donec in vestibulum nulla. Phasellus id justo purus. Aliquam et massa accumsan lectus dapibus ullamcorper. Praesent bibendum suscipit urna nec vestibulum. Fusce eget mauris eget enim blandit auctor. Morbi orci ligula, vestibulum sit amet viverra non, sollicitudin eu nisl. Maecenas ultrices tincidunt quam quis malesuada. Maecenas lobortis mi varius tortor consectetur ut gravida nunc sagittis. Aliquam risus tortor, laoreet congue consectetur in, convallis eget leo. Nunc enim nisl, ornare sit amet tristique ut, aliquet a lectus. Cras ut elit risus. Maecenas consectetur pharetra mi, id eleifend justo vulputate eget. Sed quis condimentum elit. Integer sit amet neque sem, viverra laoreet mauris. Aenean in libero augue, id euismod mauris. Cras massa urna, imperdiet tincidunt egestas sit amet, porta ac diam. Curabitur ligula nisl, cursus eget porttitor non, sagittis nec sapien.
```

Comment: the style may also be conflicting with another style (from elsewhere)

Comment: @Theo: was just about to add that.

Answer (score 0):

Use **window** instead of **document** as below:

```
window.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is like mine when i had this problem
which was to disable scroll when a sidebar menu appears from the left or right
all i did is instead of

```html
      document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
```

i did

```html
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
```

and it worked but if you wanna specify the Y or X scroll i tried everything out there but this did the trick for my case

Comment: i did not realise this was 11 years ago lmao but yeah hopefully it works for someone else